# Laravel-mix spread operator: Unexpected token

Tags: laravel, babeljs, webpack-2, laravel-mix

I'm trying to use [vue-admin](https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin) with [laravel-mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) but every time I run 
`npm run dev`

It always fails with:

`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   store,
|   nprogress,
|   ...App
| })
|`

I am aware of the one possible solution here: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/76

Tried node versions: 6.x, 7.x

But creating a .babelrc file with the plugin does not help. Is it possible, that somehow the babelrc is overwritten when compiling the vue-admin module?

Do I have to add a custom query to the webpack config?

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Comment: I gave up and did it without laravel mix: https://github.com/gazben/laravel-vue-admin

Comment: Adding the plugin fixes the issue where your compiler does not understand the spread operator (...), and the expected error for that would be `Unexpected token`. Looks like the error you got, `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`, was something else instead.